# Dados não mapeados schema graphql

Tags: graphql

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida em relação ao GraphQL.

Possuo uma API que recebe determinados dados do usuário, por exemplo: Nome, email, endereço e etc... e além destes dados já pré definidos, é possível salvar dados adicionais, que não são definidos. Me surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

Como eu defino o tipo desses dados, pois não consegui encontrar na documentação um tipo "objeto".

Por exemplo:

```
    type Query {
    user: User
}

type User {
    id: ID!,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    extra: Object //este seria um objeto customizado
}
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em `GraphQL` todos os dados tem que ser um objeto `json` valido, ou seja, tem que ter `key` e `value`.

Uma das formas para mapear os dados seria definir um `type` com os respetivos valores:

```
type UserExtra {
  valor1: String,
  valor2: Number,
  ...
}

type User {
    id: ID!,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    extra: UserExtra
}
```

Mas para usar este formato tem que saber a `key` dos valores retornados em `extra`(valor1, valor2...).

Se não sabe a `key` dos valores retornados em `extra` pode definir um [Scalar Type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types) para o type `json` usando a library [graphql-type-json](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json), desta forma os valores em `extra` serão mapeados como json.

Comment: Obrigado pela ideia!